# Possible Conference Speaking Sponsorships -- 2011

Tags: discussion, conferences

We're evaluating the feasibility of **sponsoring a member of the English community to speak at a conference in 2011**.

Speaking is a relatively big "ask", so this needs to be planned many months in advance. Let's get started!

We'd like the community to establish **where** ...

> What relevant english language conferences are coming up in 2011 that have open speaker slots or calls for papers?

... and then **who**.

> Which members of the community are strongly interested in being sponsored by Stack Exchange, Inc to speak at one of the above conferences in 2011?

To be clear, the speaker is free to talk about anything he or she wants, so long as it would be roughly on topic for this site and there is a quick acknowledgement of support from Stack Exchange and a mention of the community here.

Comment: Related: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/747/are-there-any-english-language-conferences-to-which-se-could-sponsor-a-member

Answer (score 3):

Although I'm rather new to this site, I've spoken at conferences before, both academic and in industry, and been sponsored in some of them by other community-oriented websites (JavaRanch, The Server-Side Java Symposium). My academic training is in English literature, including doctoral study. I'm also interested generally in doing more large-audience presentations.

I can do some digging around for relevant conferences. Since I'm just north of Silicon Valley there may be something locally that's interested in how this kind of community works. If it were feasible, a panel discussion would be particularly cool, as I imagine the motivations we each have can be quite different.